# jQuery Deferredでthenが処理を待ってくれない

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

コメントアウトしている箇所は正しく動作するのですが、一番下のDeferredインスタンスを利用する方法だと、処理を待たずにdelayメソッドが同時に実行されてしまします。何故なのでしょうか？

```
delay = (msg)->
  $.Deferred (p)->
    setTimeout ->
      console.log msg
      p.resolve()
    ,1000

#delay('test').done ->
#  delay('test2').done ->
#    delay('test3').done ->

#delay('start')
#.then ->delay(1)
#.then ->delay(2)
#.then ->delay(3)

#$.Deferred().resolve()
#.then ->delay(1)
#.then ->delay(2)
#.then ->delay(3)

d = new $.Deferred()

d.then ->delay(1)
d.then ->delay(2)
d.then ->delay(3)

d.resolve()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d9prbjg0/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.Deferred().resolve()
.then ->delay(1)
.then ->delay(2)
.then ->delay(3)
```

この例では `then()` が返した Deferred オブジェクトに対して `then()` を実行していますよね。これをメソッドチェインを使わずに書くなら一度変数に入れる必要があります。

```
d = $.Deferred().resolve()
d = d.then ->delay(1)
d = d.then ->delay(2)
d = d.then ->delay(3)
```

それを踏まえて、ご質問のコードを修正してみました。

```
d1 = $.Deferred()

d = d1.then -> delay(1)
d = d.then -> delay(2)
d.then -> delay(3)

d1.resolve()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jrp3kvuq/1/

[`$.Deferred()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) で新しいインスタンスを返すので new は不要です。また、  `resolve()` したいのは最初の Deferred オブジェクトですから、 `d1` として別にしてあります。

なお、 then で Deferred オブジェクトを返してしまうと、それを受け取った側が `resolve()` `reject()` できてしまいます。コールバックの設定だけさせたいなら、代わりに [`promise()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) で取得した Promise オブジェクトを返すべきです。

[爆速でわかるjQuery.Deferred超入門 - Yahoo! JAPAN Tech Blog](http://techblog.yahoo.co.jp/programming/jquery-deferred/)

Comment: とても参考になりました！$.Deferred (d)->というような呼び方をした場合には自動的にpromiseを返してくれるのだと都合よく解釈していました。次のようにjQueryを拡張してみます。http://jsfiddle.net/89753umn/

Comment: その `$.then` は、標準の [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) で代用できそうです。 http://jsfiddle.net/s027sq8r/1/